# Delete entire row based on duplicates in Column Y and keep the last record

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am working with a dataset that is refreshed when a sharepoint survey is completed, and the responses to that survey are then exported to a table in Excel. I want to be able to delete an entire row(s) if the ZIP code (string) of the facility reviewed (Column Y) is the same, but I want to keep the most-recent survey response, or that which appears in the higher row value.

For example, row 38 contains a survey response with a ZIP code string of "33138." Row 52 (survey completed more-recently), was also completed for ZIP code "33138." I want to delete row 38, and retain row 52.

Looking for a VBA solution.

@BigBen I've tried this code, which I found on a few discussion boards. Also note, I plan run this from a button on "Dashboard" tab for records on the "data" tab.

```
Sub deduplicate()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long
Dim Lst As Long, nRng As Range
Lst = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For n = Lst To 1 Step -1
    If Not .Exists(Range("Y" & n).Value) Then
        .Add Range("Y" & n).Value, Nothing
    Else
        If nRng Is Nothing Then
            Set nRng = Range("Y" & n)
        Else
            Set nRng = Union(nRng, Range("Y" & n))
        End If
End If
Next n
If Not nRng Is Nothing Then nRng.EntireRow.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

@BigBen, as part of a longer script, I also tried the following code. It sort of worked, but only removed the first instance of a duplicate, and not all duplicate rows.

```
Worksheets("Data").Activate
Dim lrow As Long

For lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lrow, "Y") = Cells(lrow, "Y").Offset(-1, 0) Then
       Cells(lrow, "Y").Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next lrow
```

Comment: What have you tried so far / where are you stuck?

Comment: Is the data on the "Data" tab formatted as a table (i.e. with Ctrl-T), or not? Are there headers?

Comment: @ BigBen. Yes, the data is in a table on "Data."

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment that the data is in a table (`ListObject`), something like this could work. This loops from the first to last row, deleting the row if a `CountIf` on the column, using the current row's value, is greater than 1.

```
Sub DedupeZipCodes()
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim zipCol As ListColumn: Set zipCol = tbl.ListColumns("Zip Code")
    Dim currentRow As Long, lastRow As Long

    With zipCol
        currentRow = 1
        lastRow = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

        Do While currentRow < lastRow
            If Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange, .DataBodyRange(currentRow).Value) > 1 Then
                .DataBodyRange(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete
                lastRow = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            Else
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            End If
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response! I am excited to test out this proposed solution in the morning. I’m very thankful for your assistance and willingness to help!

Comment: your code worked brilliantly! Thank you SO much!! I hope you have a wonderful day!